# Is there an eval() function in scss?

Tags: html, css, sass

Is there a function to execute a `scss` string like [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) in JavaScript?

```css
$color: red;
$myColor: '$color'

* {
  color: #{eval($myColor)}; /* color: red; */
}
```

Comment: AFAIK there is not. What is your use case for it?

Comment: I don't have an use case for it (this type of function shouldn't be used) but I was wondering if there was one.